# An efficient way to update the database table

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

I have a `Student` entity, a `Team` entity. Then I created a `StudentTeam` entity which have the fields "`student_id`", "`team_id`" and "`updateTime`".

`Student` entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
  private Set<StudentTeam> studentTeams = new HashSet<StudentTeam>();

  //Getter & Setter
}
```

`Student` & `StudentTeam` have **OneToMany** relationship.

`Team` entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "team")
public class Team {

  private int tid;
  private String name;
  private String city;

  //Getter & Setter
}
```

The `team` table in **DB** looks like this:

```
tid   name   city
___  ______  _____
1    name1   city_A
2    name1   city_B
3    name3   city_C
...
```

That's different team instances could have the **same** `name` but **different** `city`

Above things work fine.

Now, my client send me a request which includes a student id, a list of team names with corresponding cities.

This client wants me to update this student's teams (update the `student_team` table in DB) with the teams it sent. TO BE NOTICED, the student might have a team with the same team `name` but different `city`. Besides, if this student have other teams in DB but not mentioned in the request, they should be kept with this student.

I am using Servlet + Hibernate. I am wondering what is the most efficient HQL to update the student's teams for this scenario?

Comment: Don't have a `group` entity. Reserved words are a nuisance.

Comment: Good. Now consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Map` collection in your mapping if it is acceptable for your requirement.  For example:

```
@Entity
public class Student {

   ...

   private String name;

   @ManyToMany @JoinTable
   @MapKeyColumn(name="city")
   private Map<String, Team> mapTeam;

   ...

}

@Entity
public class Team {

   ...

   String name

   ...
}
```

The mapping above requires three tables: `student`, `team` and `student_team`.

You can add new `Team` to a `Student` with code like this:

```
student.getMapTeam().put('City_A', team1);
student.getMapTeam().put('City_B', team1);
student.getMapTeam().put('City_C', team2);
```

You only need to query for a `Student` entity.  Then, you can retrieve all `Team` and its associated city by calling `getMapTeam()`.